# crystal report problem

Tags: crystal-reports

what is the equivalant command like in vb for EOF(), MoveNext, Moveprevious commands in crystal reports

Answer (score 3):

There are no equivalent answers in Crystal Reports, at least not in the versions I have used.  Crystal Reports more or less simply dumps the data out into the report.

That said, if you are in a detail row, and you want to find out what the next value of a field will be, you can use:

```
next({YourColumn})
```

You can also find out the previous column value by using this:

```
previous({YourColumn})
```

Keep in mind that `Next()` won't work on the last record, and `Previous()` won't work on the first record.

I'll have to double-check, but I believe there is an `OnLastRecord` function that returns TRUE if you are on the last record.

Answer (score 2):

First, welcome to SO!

Second, <strike>you sound new to</strike>  Crystal Report's purpose is to display data, not perform the kind of calculations you're talking about.  CR usually goes record-by-record through the data, displaying (or suppressing) each record, and adding group headers & footers.

To answer your question, LittleBobbyTables does give a few good pointers.  To see the entire list of functions available to you, there is a list in the Formula Editor (see pic below).  Press F1 for detailed descriptions of each command.

You can also:

1. Create a "Running Total Formula" that will evaluate each record and give a calculation in the group footer.
2. Do the calculations outside of Crystal Reports and only feed the end result in (perhaps with an unlinked join to your primary table).
3. The most complex option is to make a subreport that does the calculation and feeds the result back to the main report

Can you give us some more details about what you're trying to do?
[image]